# RDFlib: Add triples to graph in bulk

Tags: python, rdf, linked-data, rdflib

I am parsing triple files and adding the triples into my local triplestore. 
Code Snippet:

```
graph = ConjunctiveGraph('Sleepycat')
graph.open("mytriplestore", create=False)
g = Graph()
g.parse("filename.ttl", format="ttl") 
for t in g:
    graph.add(t)
```

Instead of iterating over every triple, is it possible to add the parsed content to the triplestore in bulk?

What I have tried so far:
Attempt 1:

```
graph.add(g)
```

Error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdflib/graph.py", line 1345, in add
s,p,o,c = self._spoc(triple_or_quad, default=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdflib/graph.py", line 1326, in _spoc
return s,p,o,c
UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment
```

Attempt 2:

```
graph.addN(g)
```

Error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdflib/graph.py", line 1363, in addN
(s, p, o, self._graph(c)) for s, p, o, c in quads if
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdflib/store.py", line 221, in addN
for s, p, o, c in quads:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdflib/graph.py", line 1363, in <genexpr>
(s, p, o, self._graph(c)) for s, p, o, c in quads if
```

ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack

Comment: `graph = graph.add(g)` doesn't work?

Comment: @AKSW Nope. Tried already.

Comment: @RDangol, perhaps `.addN()` or something like.

Comment: @StanislavKralin That did not work either

Comment: @RDangol Tied and didn't add the graph or lead to an exception? From the docs, `Graph::__add__` should return a new graph which is the union of the current graph and the other graph.

Comment: @AKSW I have updated the Qn with details

Answer (score 3):

Addition of graph should do the trick :

```
graph += g
```